# How properly convert ArrayList to String in MEL

Tags: mule, mule-esb, mel

so I have payload and part of it have array like such:

```
{
...
members [
  John,
  Robert,
  Tony
]
...
}
```

I try to set variable as:

```
#[payload.members joinBy(",")]
```

but its return it type as java.lang.ArrayList

however if doing same with DW  1.0 (output to variable):

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload.members joinBy ","
```

I receive it as needed type - java.lang.String

Any advice why it so or what I am doing wrong to get in MEL same as in transform component? (I am traying avoid using transform component for such simple step)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two different languages. Mule 3.x uses [MEL](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mule-expression-language-mel) as its expression language. That means that every expression of the form `#[...]` is a MEL expression. Mule 3.7+ also supports [DataWeave 1](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/dataweave-reference-documentation) *inside the Transform component*. Those are two different languages. The [joinBy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/dataweave-operators#join-by) operation is a DataWeave operation so it is not expected to work in a MEL expression. I'm not sure why it is not just throwing an error.

In MEL you could do something like this:

```
#[ org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(payload.members, ",") ]
```

Most basic Java expressions are compatible with MEL.

Note that in Mule 4 the only expression language is DataWeave 2. There expressions work the same inside `#[...]` than in the Transform component.

Comment: yes we are still with v.3.8 so I understand a difference but my question is how with MEL get same result - convert from json array into string, similar to dw result. Error is not throw as syntax is correct, but result unexpected.

Comment: I don't believe that the syntax is correct for MEL. If you try `#[payload.members]` you will see it returns the same ArrayList. For some reason the joinBy() is ignored. That syntax is only valid in DataWeave. What's unexpected is the lack of a syntax error. As a sidenote I recommend to migrate to newer versions of Mule. Version 3.8 is in End of Life as of last month.

Comment: As a proof try this expression that doesn't throw an error either: `#[payload.members nonsense()]`. Clearly there is no `nonsense()` function anywhere but it doesn't throw an error. Probably a bug.

Comment: organisation planning to migrate to Kong API so they not spending on migration of mule :( however I still need to support that they have so trying to optimise to get more speed a bit. yes well spotted - nonsense () also don't throw error, so perhaps its a bug :( but still question is is it possible in MEL turn array into string?

Comment: I already mentioned a possible valid MEL expression to achieve that.

Comment: oh yes, its wasn't work initially after rebuild its working now, thanks again